# How to pick the "sigma" when sigma clipping?

Tags: regression, outliers

In astronomy (and I'm sure in other places as well) it is very common to use sigma-clipping as the outlier rejection scheme. The idea is that you regress the data, subtract the fit from the points, and then reject all points with residuals exceeding some sigma times either the standard deviation or median absolute deviation.

My question: is there a good way to automatically select sigma based on the data? I have some points that have very high quality observations -- the measurement might be 15 magnitudes and the the error on measurement is something like 0.000001 -- and some with much lower quality observations -- error around 0.05.

I'd think that one would want different values of sigma for these different cases. Any ideas? Heuristics are fine for my purposes.

Comment: This approach has some problems; for example, only a few percent of observations at 100sd's from the mean of the 'good data' is enough to mask all the outliers. That said, I think that different circumstances may well call for different criteria. Unfortunately, I can't quite follow what you're saying. When you say 'the measurement might be 15 magnitudes' it sounds ambiguous -- what exactly are you saying? When you say 'error on measurement is something like 0.000001', is that relative error? Are you able to give some sense of what properties you seek in the resulting procedures?

Comment: So if the instrument measures 15, and the uncertainty on that measurement is .0001, then measurement is really somewhere between 14.999 and 15.0001. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does. The "magnitudes" threw me on the first one.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. You can basically think of "magnitude" as a measure of brightness.